# Maven - Generate latest release jar when pom version is snapshot

Tags: maven, release, target

Latest release of my app is 2.0.

In my pom.xml I have 2.1-SNAPSHOT as version

I want to generate my-app-2.0.jar (not my-app-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) in /target

Simple as that, anyone knows? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the last released version ? Generally, it is a bad idea as it hurts the history of versions.

Comment: No, I just want to generate again an old artifact (the latest), in this case my-app-2.0.jar.

Comment: You should checkout the tag of the project on your SCM and rebuild it.

Comment: If you put that into an answer I can mark it as correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome. I did an answer and added some details about the reliability of tags. It may matter sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the exact source code of the released component, you should checkout the `tag` of this version of the component on your SCM (source control management) that ideally should be a unmodifiable directory to reflect exactly the source code of the released component.
This is not always the case.
 So, you could check this point and the history of the tag folder to ensure of it.

Then rebuild the checked-out project with the `mvn clean package` command.